# Will there be any historical "milestone" anymore if we had achieve teaching philosophy and other knowledge

Tags: analytic-philosophy

Will there be any historical greatest "milestone" anymore if we had achieve teaching philosophy and any kind of other knowledge either by using computer or by human teaching through computer by using the most optimal speed.

If we define the greatest milestone to be able to produce any smaller milestone, then what is the answer to the above question?

Also, My friend is a computer engineer and he want to produce either a computer philosopher(a computer) or a  philosophical engineer that will be able to use computer optimize his speed of teaching, so which option is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need axioms to feed the computer with. Finding which axioms are the more interesting is not a matter of computation, but of understanding. That is precisely the role of philosophy.
Arguably, important milestones are achieved when new fruitful axiomatic systems (theories) are discovered which are fruitful and apply well to the world, but that cannot be achieved by computation alone.
Stated in a kuhnian vocabulary: computation is helpful for normal science, but not for paradigm change or scientific revolutions.
So I would say no important milestone can ever be reached through computation alone.